# Entity Framework Core is lazy loading when transforming

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm having an issue with Entity Framework Core (v2.0.1) when transforming an entity model into a DTO. Basically it is, by any other version of the phrase, lazy loading when I don't want it to. Here's a simple .NET Core Console application (with the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.0.1) package).

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace EfCoreIssue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ReportDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=EfCoreIssue;Trusted_Connection=True;")
                .Options;

            // Create and seed database if it doesn't already exist.
            using (var dbContext = new ReportDbContext(dbOptions))
            {
                if (dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated())
                {
                    string alphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

                    foreach (char alpha in alphas)
                    {
                        var report = new Report { Title = $"Report { alpha }" };

                        for (int tagId = 0; tagId < 10; tagId++)
                            report.Tags.Add(new ReportTag { TagId = tagId });

                        dbContext.Reports.Add(report);
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var dbContext = new ReportDbContext(dbOptions))
            {
                var reports = dbContext.Reports
                    .Select(r => new ReportDto
                    {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Title = r.Title,
                        Tags = r.Tags.Select(rt => rt.TagId)
                    })
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    class ReportDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }

        public ReportDbContext(DbContextOptions<ReportDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ReportTag>().HasKey(rt => new { rt.ReportId, rt.TagId });
        }
    }

    [Table("Report")]
    class Report
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ReportTag> Tags { get; set; }

        public Report()
        {
            Tags = new HashSet<ReportTag>();
        }
    }

    [Table("ReportTag")]
    class ReportTag
    {
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
    }

    class ReportDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now when the `ToList()` method is executed to retrieve the data, it's executing the following SQL

```
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Title]
FROM [Report] AS [r]
```

As you can see, it has made no effort to join to the `[ReportTag]` table, and if you actually try and read the values of the `Tags` property on a `ReportDto` then it fires off another SQL query

```
SELECT [rt].[TagId]
FROM [ReportTag] AS [rt]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [rt].[ReportId]
```

Now I know EF Core doesn't support lazy loading, but this looks very much like lazy loading to me. In this instance I don't want it to lazy load. I've tried changing `var reports = dbContext.Reports` to `var reports = dbContext.Reports.Include(r => r.Tags)` which has no effect.

I've even tried changing `Tags = r.Tags.Select(rt => rt.TagId)` to `Tags = r.Tags.Select(rt => rt.TagId).ToList()` but that just fires off the above secondary SQL query a further 26 times.

Finally in desperation I tried changing `var reports = dbContext.Reports` to `var reports = dbContext.Reports.Include(r =>
 r.Tags).ThenInclude((ReportTag rt) => rt.TagId)` but that understandably throws an exception that `ReportTag.TagId` isn't a navigation property.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do so that it eager loads into the `ReportDto.Tags` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, currently there are two problems with EF Core projection queries containing collection projections - (1) they cause execution of N queries per collection and (2) they are executed lazily.

Problem (2) is weird, because ironically EF Core does not support *lazy loading* related entity data, while this behavior effectively implements it for projections. At least you can force immediate execution by using `ToList()` or similar, as you already found.

Problem (1) is unresolvable at this time. It's tracked by [Query: optimize queries projecting correlated collections, so that they don't result in N+1 database queries #9282](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9282) and according to the [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap) (**Reduce n + 1 queries** item) will eventually be fixed (improved) in the next EF Core 2.1 release.

The only workaround I can think of is (with the cost of higher data transfer and memory usage) to use *eager loading* and do the projection afterwards (in the context of LINQ to Entities):

```
var reports = dbContext.Reports
    .Include(r => r.Tags) // <-- eager load
    .AsEnumerable() // <-- force the execution of the LINQ to Entities query
    .Select(r => new ReportDto
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Title = r.Title,
        Tags = r.Tags.Select(rt => rt.TagId)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Cheers Ivan for identifying the exact issue/bug at hand. The solution of loading the dataset into memory before projecting it doesn't help me too much unfortunately as it is very big and I can't modify the contract to not allow LINQ operations of the returned DTOs. I'll keep me eye on whether it gets fixed/updated during the 2.1 release.