# Error when filtering on an Include in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have the following EF Core linq statement:

```
var contact = dataContext.Contacts
                    .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                        .ThenInclude(a => a.AddressType)
                    .Where(c => c.ContactId == contactId)
                    .Select(c => new Contact()
                    {
                        ContactId = c.ContactId,
                        Title = c.Title,
                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                        Surname = c.Surname,
                        Addresses = c.Addresses.Where(a => a.IsPrimary)
                    })
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

... that gives the following error when invoked:

> Expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TeenyCRM.DataModel.Address]'
>   of method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TeenyCRM.DataModel.Address]
>   _ToEnumerable[Address](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TeenyCRM.DataModel.Address])''

If put a `.ToList()` on the Addresses projection, it executes without erroring:

i.e.

```
var contact = dataContext.Contacts
                    .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                        .ThenInclude(a => a.AddressType)
                    .Where(c => c.ContactId == contactId)
                    .Select(c => new Contact()
                    {
                        ContactId = c.ContactId,
                        Title = c.Title,
                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                        Surname = c.Surname,
                        Addresses = c.Addresses.Where(a => a.IsPrimary).ToList()
                    })
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

However, EF Core generates and executes 2 SQL statements behind the scenes.

**Is there any way to get this working, only generating a single SQL statement  behind the scenes?**

Comment: EF Core does not use single SQL for queries which include sub collections. In the best case, it executes `1 + C` SQL queries, where `C` is the count of sub collections. In the worst case like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223828/entity-framework-core-is-lazy-loading-when-transforming/48227195#48227195) - `1 + N * C` SQL queries. There is nothing you can do about it. The later is bug and will be fixed, but the former (`1 + C` queries) is by design.