# EF Core 2.0.2 generates multiple query for a subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am not sure if it's a bug not but I am getting some major performance issue. EF Core is generating multiple query for a simple statement.

This is the query:

```
        var query = (from task in db.Tasks
                     let LastStatus = task.TaskStatus.Where(x => x.Deleted == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(x => x.Status.Name).First()
                     select new
                     {
                         task.Id,
                         LastStatus
                     }).ToList();
```

Expected resuts:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[Name]
    FROM [TaskStatus] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Status] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[StatusId]
    WHERE ([t1].[TaskId] = [t0].[Id]) AND (NOT ([t1].[Deleted] = 1))
    ORDER BY [t1].[CreatedDate] DESC
    ) AS [LastStatus]
FROM [Tasks] AS [t0]
```

However EF is generating:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [x.Status0].[Name]
FROM [TaskStatus] AS [x0]
INNER JOIN [Status] AS [x.Status0] ON [x0].[StatusId] = [x.Status0].[Id]
WHERE ([x0].[TaskId] = @_outer_Id) AND ([x0].[Deleted] = 0)
ORDER BY [x0].[CreatedDate] DESC
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@_outer_Id='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [x.Status0].[Name]
FROM [TaskStatus] AS [x0]
INNER JOIN [Status] AS [x.Status0] ON [x0].[StatusId] = [x.Status0].[Id]
WHERE ([x0].[TaskId] = @_outer_Id) AND ([x0].[Deleted] = 0)
ORDER BY [x0].[CreatedDate] DESC
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
Tested with EF core 2.1.0-preview2-final still the same issue

Comment: Why are you using `db.TaskStatus` instead of `task.TaskStatus`?

Comment: mistake, changed to let LastStatus = task.TaskStatus.Where same results

Comment: Yeah no, System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not parse expression 'task.TaskStatus.ToList()':

Comment: Sorry it was totally wrong.... sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You can test this one: `let LastStatus = task.TaskStatus.Where(x => x.Deleted == false).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(x => x.Status.Name).First()
                     select new`

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223828/entity-framework-core-is-lazy-loading-when-transforming. Hopefully will be fixed in 2.1 But if you want to be sure, consider posting it to EF Core issue tracker.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi: Same Not supported

Comment: @IvanStoev: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11677

Comment: @Zulander Cool. At least you'll know if you can expect to be fixed in 2.1 Also you can try the 2.1 pre-release build yourself. Good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev Not fixed in 2.1.0-preview2-final

Comment: @Zulander Too bad. But it's not too late, may be your post will show them a missed case that can easily be fixed, who knows.

Comment: EF Core is a major fallback compared with EF 6 in terms of query to SQL translation. Not sure why EF6 translation code could not be reused in one or another way.

Comment: @Zulander I see they closed the issue. Is it resolved and how? In 2.0.2 using `FirstOrDefault` and not using `let` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @IvanStoev the FirstOrDefault resolved my problem in 2.1.0-preview2-final. So we upgraded our project. Didn't test in 2.0.2 (since we upgraded it). Also See last the comment on git for the issue with "let" keyword

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgraded to EF 2.0.2 to EF core 2.1.0-preview2-final
2. Used FirstOrDefault() instead of First(),
3. Don't use "let" ("There are known problem when the sub query defined using let appears more than once later") See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11677 details